# Applied settings not saving in My.Settings

Tags: vb.net

I've tried making a popup settings form for my VB.NET program, but the settings are not being saved after the user closes the application.

On the popup form's code to save an API key + some other things I have:

```
My.Settings.apiKey = txtAPI.Text
```

On the close event for the popup. If I then close my application & reopen it, none of the data gets saved (which it should...).

Note: I am doing

```
txtAPI.Text = My.Settings.API
```

on the settings form load event to show the API key as soon as you click the settings button.

Thanks!

Comment: You should call `My.Settings.Save` to save the data. After assigning values to settings `My.Settings.apiKey = txtAPI.Text` etc...  now use  `My.Settings.Save`

Comment: *Project menu > Project properties > Application tab > Save My.Settings on Shutdown* Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @o_O Thanks, seems like I missed that when I was reading over the documentation!